# Entity Framework Core - Using Stored Procedure with output parameters

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use stored procedures with new Entity Framework Core. I need to start new project soon which will be ASP.Net 5, but not sure if Entity Framework will fit for the job. The application will be triggering several stored procedures per minute and I need output parameters. Will EF be good for this or should I use ADO.Net?

I have tried FromSql and database.ExecuteSqlCommand but no luck.

```
using (AppDbContext db = factory.Create())
        {
            var in1 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "ParamIn1",
                DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int64,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
            };
            var in2 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "ParamIn2",
                DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
            };
            var out1 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "ParamOut1",
                DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int64,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
            };
            var out2 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "ParamOut2",
                DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
            };

            var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec spTestSp", in1, in2, out1, out2);
        }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should work, but I believe you also need to include the parameter names and the `OUT` keyword in the command statement

```
var sql = "exec spTestSp @ParamIn1, @ParamIn2, @ParamOut1 OUT, @ParamOut2 OUT";
var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, in1, in2, out1, out2);

var out1Value = (long) out1.Value;
var out2Value = (string) out2.Value;
```

Comment: Confirmed this works.  There are several variations of how to do this floating around which do not work.

Comment: Whenever paste be sure to **Set Length for OUT PARAMETER** 
`SqlParameter job1 = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@job", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);`

Comment: @Muflix it was giving an error to me when I was not specifying Length

Comment: Can you please provide full example with parameter declares ?

Answer (score 6):

```
**This is a working example**

1)  Create sample SP

--exec [dbo].sampleCalc 100,0,''
CREATE PROCEDURE[dbo].sampleCalc
   @inputPara int,
   @outputPara1 INT OUTPUT,
   @outputPara2 varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    set @outputPara1 = @inputPara + 100
    set @outputPara2 = 'result is ' + convert(varchar(50), @outputPara1)
    print @outputPara1
    print @outputPara2
END

2) C#

var param = new SqlParameter[] {
new SqlParameter() {
 ParameterName = "@inputPara",
 SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
 Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
 Value = 100
},
new SqlParameter() {
 ParameterName = "@outputPara1",
 SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
 Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
},
new SqlParameter() {
 ParameterName = "@outputPara2",
 SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
 Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
 Size = 50
}};


var sql = "exec sampleCalc @inputPara, @outputPara1 OUT, @outputPara2 OUT";
var resultObj = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, param.ToArray());

var out1Value = param[1].Value.ToString();
var out2Value = param[2].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Please explain why and how this complements all existing answers. It's not necessary to post new answers if they don't show anything essentially new.

Comment: @GertArnold I believe that DEEPMOC was trying to show how this could be done using the Entity Framework ExecuteSqlRaw method. It helped me with my question!

Comment: Me too, IIRC I had to use ExecuteSqlRaw because of Blazor and IDbContextFactory recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Full example of the solution as described above by @Nkosi and partially by @Whistler for the ease of future readers!

In my example, I was trying to execute a stored procedure existed in my database to get specific path.

```
string tableName = "DocumentStore";
string path;

        var in1 = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "TableName",
            Value = tableName,
            Size = Int32.MaxValue,
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
        };

        var out1 = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "Path",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = Int32.MaxValue,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
        };

        //_context is DbContext Object
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC GetFileTableRootPath @TableName, @Path OUT", in1,out1);

        path = out1.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: if someone comes up here, Size is meant for the size of the data type's Byte (e.g. 4 for int32 or 8 for int64) or the string size described in the sql table, like varchar(32) with size=32

Answer (score 2):

The [StoredProcedureEFCore](https://github.com/verdie-g/StoredProcedureEFCore) extention supports output parameters

Then the usage is like this

```
List<Model> rows = null;

ctx.LoadStoredProc("dbo.ListAll")
   .AddParam("limit", 300L)
   .AddParam("limitOut", out IOutParam<long> limitOut)
   .Exec(r => rows = r.ToList<Model>());

long limitOutValue = limitOut.Value;

ctx.LoadStoredProc("dbo.ReturnBoolean")
   .AddParam("boolean_to_return", true)
   .ReturnValue(out IOutParam<bool> retParam)
   .ExecNonQuery();

bool b = retParam.Value;

ctx.LoadStoredProc("dbo.ListAll")
   .AddParam("limit", 1L)
   .ExecScalar(out long l);
```