# Convert Sql server statement into Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I have SP written on SQL Server:

- the input is `XML`
- It has a different OUTPUT

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspMyProcedure](
@XML XML,
@FamilySent INT = 0 OUTPUT ,
@FamilyImported INT = 0 OUTPUT)
```

- The status is returned via `RETURN` and `SELECT` is also called

```sql
SELECT Result FROM @tblResult
RETURN 0 --ALL OK
END
```

How to convert this procedure to C#, Net. Core, EntityFrameworkCore using LINQ?

*The question about SP was already asked, but I can not find the answer for this situation*

Comment: See following : https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252959/entity-framework-core-using-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters

Comment: Do you need to run the SP server side, or could you convert it to a client side XML processor?

Answer (score 0):

[how to load SP in EDMX:](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)

P.S. if you using select in SP with variables in EF. dont forget to add this line in SP:

```
 SET FMTONLY OFF
```