# How to utilize output parameters in EF Core 3.0 using ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

[Microsoft doesn't have any current documentation on output parameters, just normal ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). I'm using .Net Core 3.0 with EF Core 3.0 and trying to get an output parameter back from my stored procedure. Code as follows:

```
var output=""
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
$"EXEC dbo.InsertTest @param1={"test"},@param2={"test2"}, @param3={output});
```

What I don't know is how to structure the new api in 3.1 to specify an output parameter. I'm wondering if anyone has any documentation on this or has done this in the new update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean output ? in your code it seems you trying to insert something?

Comment: @rasti: It's implied that `@param3` is an output parameter.

Comment: sorry I didn't give attention to that, what do u get ? and why u use await

Comment: I'm using await because I'm taking the output parameter and using it to make another method call. @madreflection is right. It is implied that param3 is an output parameter. In the past I would have used something like this and I'm just trying to replicate it with the new "ExecuteSqlInterpolated":
 await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("dbo.InsertTest param1,param2, param3 OUT", parameters: new[] { param1,param2, output });

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks to Eugene for putting me on the right track. In case someone stumbles across this same problem:

To successfully get an output parameter in 3.0, you have to specifically define the output parameter as a SqlParameter() and then include the word "OUT" **after** your variable.

This is an example of using ExecuteSqlInterpolated()

```
var output = new SqlParameter();
output.ParameterName = "@ID";
output.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
"EXEC dbo.InsertTest @param1={'test'},@param2={'test2'}, @param3={output} OUT");
```

This is an example of using ExecuteSqlRawAsync()

```
var output = new SqlParameter();
output.ParameterName = "@ID";
output.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
"EXEC dbo.InsertTest @param1={0},@param2={1}, @param3={3} OUT", param1,param2,output);
```

Comment: In what way? At the time of that post, these examples were working flawlessly.

Comment: Your " quotes aren't escaped around "test" and "test2", so I doubt they ever worked as shown here. Was maybe some formatting lost when posting or editing? For example I use _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"EXECUTE [dbo].[SP_Something] @ParamA='fixed value', @ParamB={model.SomeValue}");

Comment: Its possible that i mistyped when I converted the answer over to stack overflow. I've updated the answer. I also noticed I was missing a closing " after OUT.

Comment: For RawAsync it should be "EXEC dbo.InsertTest @param1={0},@param2={1}, @param3={2} OUT", param1,param2,output); rather than having {3}

Answer (score 3):

There is a small chance that creating `param3` as [DbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbparameter?view=netcore-3.1)/`SqlParameter` with `Direction` set to `Output` may work:

```
var output = new SqlParameter("@param3", DbType.String)
    { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
    $"EXEC dbo.InsertTest @param1={"test"},@param2={"test2"}, @param3={output}");
Console.WriteLine(output.Value);
```

But I'm not sure about that from what I can see from the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/5023d9dc59b2cf4adec809a9775253aa7f74a916/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L348) and can't check it now with actual DB.

So in the worst case you would just have to drop `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` and use some standard way to execute stored procedures that supports output parameters - [Entity Framework Core - Using Stored Procedure with output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252959/entity-framework-core-using-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters)

Comment: Eugene, this was the route that I started going down. I tested it a few different ways... As a sqlParameter, as a string, as an int, etc... The SqlParameter is the only option that does work. However, the caveat is that you also need to include the word "OUT" after the variable in order to get anything back. As I noted in my follow-up post, the combination of these two items are what was holding me back.