# Getting one from Entity Framework Core calling a stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to call a stored procedure using Entity Framework Core. The stored procedure is little bit complicated so I am not using LINQ.

This is my code:

```
using (IdentityProofContext dc =  new IdentityProofContext())
{
    SqlParameter[] @params =
        {
            new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int) {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}
        };


    dc.IdentityPersonalData.FromSqlRaw("Execute usp_GetIdentityProofStatus", @params).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    //var result = @params[0].Value;
    //if (result > 0)
    //{
    //    MiscEmails.sendEmails();
    //}
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetStatus
    (@result int OUTPUT)
AS
    SELECT @result = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.TestData
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DateInserted, GETDATE()) < 120 --Number of minutes
      AND STATUS IN ('test1' )

    RETURN @result
```

Any help with calling a stored procedure using Entity Framework Core to return a single value will be highly appreciated.

I also tried looking at this link:

[Entity Framework Core - Using Stored Procedure with output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252959/entity-framework-core-using-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters)

I don't see anything that says: `ExecuteSqlCommand`. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

These are the frameworks that I am using:

[image]

I am using a .NET Core console application, and these are the using statements in my `.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using EVitalsStatusCheck.DAL.DB;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EVitalsStatusCheck.DAL;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: You should not have deleted your original post, just responded with an edit or a comment

Comment: Are you still on Entity Framework 3 by any chance? Current version is 6.2

Comment: What does result represent relative to the IdentityPersonalData entity?  It needs to map.  If you can't map it, just use Dapper and save yourself the headache by working outside of an individual entity.

Comment: I trying doing it, but still it was saying your question is close, ask a new one

Comment: I am using entity framework 6.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your DbContext like this:

```
    public int GetStatus()
    {
        var result = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
        
        this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec usp_GetIdentityProofStatus @result out", result);

        return (int)result.Value;
    }
```

And the stored procedure should not return a data value.  The return value of a stored procedure should be 0 on success, or it should raise an error on failure.

So it should be

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetStatus
    (@result int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.TestData
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DateInserted, GETDATE()) < 120 --Number of minutes
      AND STATUS IN ('test1' )
END
```

Comment: Thanks. Just changed the ExecuteSQLCommand to ExecuteSqlRaw and it worked right away.

Answer (score 1):

From [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-5.0).

> For the execution of SQL queries using plain strings, use ExecuteSqlRaw instead. For the execution of SQL queries using interpolated string syntax to create parameters, use ExecuteSqlInterpolated instead.

Because your EFCore version is 5.0, so method `ExecuteSqlCommand` is obsolete, you can use `ExecuteSqlRaw`  and `ExecuteSqlInterpolated`  to replace it.

Comment: I used ExecuteSqlRaw instead of ExecuteSQLCommand