# Entity framework core Output parameter not working in store procedure using FromSql method (Linq)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get output value from the `dbcontext` using the method `FromSql(...)`.

If i execute it on SSMS, it works but not working in EF core.

**My SP param:**

```
  @totalItems VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
```

I've removed other params for readable and point out the issue. The records are coming  but the `OUTPUT` parameter is always `null`.

**Linq**

```
IQeryable<T> = _context.Set<T>().FromSql("Sp_Todo @totalItems OUTPUT", // i also tried with OUT or without both Out/Output but no luck
 new SqlParameter("@totalItems", SqlDbType.Varchar)
 { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output});
```

Comment: Your database is using VARCHAR while the c# query has BigInt.

Comment: Even if i put `SqlDbType.VarChar`  returns null.

Comment: try "string query=" in place of "var query="

Comment: **Ashu** The query isn't the string. It is `IQeryable<T>` You can see at `_context.Set<T>()`

Comment: Not an answer, but it should be `IQueryable`, not `IQeryable`. Also, you can use @ to mention people in comments. For example, @Robin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get output parameter value of a stored procedure using EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621262/get-output-parameter-value-of-a-stored-procedure-using-ef-core)

Comment: **@Stybl** Pointing to the correct solution is helpful instead of Typo error.

Comment: Hey **@Alex** Thanks but there is no solution for this method i am using.

Answer (score 2):

I don't' have access to your whole code, but nothing ever gets executed against your queryable source until you try to enumerate it. So, probably it didn't run the Stored Procedure when you tried to get the OUTPUT.

To force immediate query evaluation you can do it:

```
 IQueryable<T> foo = _context.Set<T>().FromSql("Sp_Todo @totalItems OUTPUT", new SqlParameter("@totalItems", SqlDbType.Varchar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
 //totalItems output still null
 var bar = foo.ToList()
 //totalItems output not null anymore
```

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
var _companyCode = new SqlParameter("CompanyCode", "HST");
var _sMsg = new SqlParameter("sMsg", "")
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
};

var sql = "exec temp_get_company @CompanyCode, @sMsg OUTPUT";

var result = context.Set<Company>().FromSql(sql, _companyCode, _sMsg).ToList();

var yourOutput = _sMsg.Value.ToString();
```