# Run entity framework core raw SQL without entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this mysql stored-procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `Counter_increment2`(IN _Id VARCHAR(80), IN _CounterType VARCHAR(10), IN IncrBy INT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Counter SET Value = @counter := Value + IncrBy WHERE Id=_Id AND CounterType=_CounterType;
    SELECT @counter as Value;
END
```

The result is:
[image]

I want to read the first cell in the first row into C# variable via EF.

I know that in the past EF provided `SqlQuery<type>` method for this kind of use.

How to do it right?

Comment: Not all database store rows in the order that they get added.  So getting first row of data can be random.  So to get data always in same order use an OrderBy and then use TOP.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: SqlQuery<long> doesn't work? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically a repeat of the question answered here:

[Get output parameter value of a stored procedure using EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621262/get-output-parameter-value-of-a-stored-procedure-using-ef-core/45802698#45802698)

Using the top answer in there helped me, though I admit that was EF Core 2.something.  Might need tweaking for 3.x, assuming that's what you're using.

Note: for the specific case you've listed here (returning a single int column on a single row), I created my own extension method something like this:

```
public static class RDFacadeExtensions
{
    public static async Task<int> ExecuteScalarQueryAsync(this DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var concurrencyDetector = databaseFacade
            .GetService<IConcurrencyDetector>();

        using (concurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection())
        {
            var rawSqlCommand = databaseFacade
                .GetService<IRawSqlCommandBuilder>()
                .Build(sql, parameters);
            var result = await rawSqlCommand
                .RelationalCommand
                .ExecuteScalarAsync(
                    databaseFacade.GetService<IRelationalConnection>(),
                    parameterValues: rawSqlCommand.ParameterValues);

            return (int)result;
        }
    }
}
```

You should then be able to simply call:

```
int result = Context.Database.ExecuteScalarQueryAsync("exec procedure...");
```

To use...

(caveat: untested in this form, have been hiding at home for a while so a bit rusty too)